# Enter Date field from picklist field and store it in a date field of an object

Tags: visualforce

[image]

I haveto create a date format like above and whatever date I am entering is in integer format .It should get stored in the contact object birthdate field.So far I have written the following code .I am getting an error

[image]

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="Example2Ctrl">
    <apex:form >
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <div class="date">
                    <span>Birth date</span>
                    <apex:selectList styleClass="date" value="{!SelectedDay}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Day}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>

                    <apex:selectList styleClass="date" value="{!SelectedMonth}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Month}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>

                    <apex:selectList styleClass="date" value="{!SelectedYear}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Year}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
         <div class="form-row">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!completeRegistration}" value="Complete Registration" />
                <!--<button type="submit">Complete Registration</button>-->
         </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
Public with sharing class Example2Ctrl{

    Public String SelectedCity{get;set;}
    Public String SelectedMonth{get;set;}
    Public String SelectedDay{get;set;}
    Public String SelectedYear{get;set;}
    public date DateToday{get;set;}
    public String DateTodayString{get;set;}
    Public String birthdate{get;set;}
    Public Date   birthdateDateFormat{get;set;}

    Id runningUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    public Example2Ctrl() {
        birthdate=SelectedMonth+'/'+SelectedDay+'/'+SelectedYear;
        birthdateDateFormat=Date.valueof(birthdate);
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getMonth() {

        List<SelectOption> MonthOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        MonthOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Month'));
        for(Integer i=01;i<13;i++){
            MonthOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));        
        }
        return MonthOptions;
    }  

    public List<SelectOption> getDay() {

        List<SelectOption> DayOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        DayOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Day'));
        for(Integer i=01;i<32;i++){
            DayOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));        
        }
        return DayOptions;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getYear() {

        List<SelectOption> YearOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
        YearOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Year'));
        DateToday=system.today();
        system.debug('DateToday@@@@'+DateToday);
        Integer DateTodayInteger= DateToday.year();

        for(Integer i=1920;i<=DateTodayInteger;i++){
            YearOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));        
        }
        return YearOptions;
    }

    public pageReference completeRegistration() {
        system.debug('completeRegistration');
        User user=[SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,ContactId FROM User WHERE ID=:runningUserId ];
        system.debug('@@@@@user'+user.ContactId);    
        Contact contact=[SELECT Id,Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE Id=:user.ContactId];
        contact.Birthdate=birthdateDateFormat;
        update contact;
        system.debug('@@@@contact'+contact);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the `birthdateDateFormat` field in your controller, and `<apex:inputField>` in your visualforce page? Doing so should allow you to use the date picker, which is probably the best for UX (user experience). It would also mean less code in your controller (no need to generate year/month/day values for the selectLists), and less validation for you to do (what happens if someone enters their birthday as 2018-2-31? February never has 31 days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Birthdate" is date field of Contact Object. Before updating the date we need to change the final date entered from UI based on logged in user`s locale. Other wise it will throw error or it will save a wrong date ( like : 01/02/1986 date For user with locale ar : 'dd/mm/yyyy' and locale lb_LU : 'mm/dd/yyyy' it will create confusion). Please use the below controller instead of yours:-

```
public with sharing class Example2Ctrl{

    public String SelectedCity{get;set;}
    public String SelectedMonth{get;set;}
    public String SelectedDay{get;set;}
    public String SelectedYear{get;set;}
    public date DateToday{get;set;}
    public String DateTodayString{get;set;}
    public String birthdate{get;set;}
    public Date birthdateDateFormat{get;set;}
    private static Map<String,String> localeToDateTimeFmtMap;
    Id runningUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    public Example2Ctrl() {

    }

    public List<SelectOption> getMonth() {

        List<SelectOption> MonthOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        MonthOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Month'));
        for(Integer i=01;i<13;i++){
            MonthOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));        
        }
        return MonthOptions;
    }  

    public List<SelectOption> getDay() {

        List<SelectOption> DayOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        DayOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Day'));
        for(Integer i=01;i<32;i++){
            DayOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));        
        }
        return DayOptions;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getYear() {

        List<SelectOption> YearOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
        YearOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Year'));
        DateToday = system.today();
        system.debug('DateToday@@@@'+DateToday);
        Integer DateTodayInteger= DateToday.year();

        for(Integer i=1920;i<=DateTodayInteger;i++){
            YearOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));        
        }
        return YearOptions;
    }

    public pageReference completeRegistration() {
        String tempDate = SelectedDay+ '/'+ SelectedMonth + '/' + SelectedYear;
        Date fnlDtIs = Example2Ctrl.setStringToDateFormat(tempDate);
        System.debug('@@@@ logged in user date:'+fnlDtIs);

        User user=[SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,ContactId FROM User WHERE ID =:runningUserId ];
        Contact contact = [SELECT Id,Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE Name=:user.FirstName];// I have changed the condition . Please change it as per ur need 
        if(contact.Id != null){
            contact.Birthdate = fnlDtIs;
            update contact;
            system.debug('@@@@contact'+contact);
        }


        return null;
    }

    //  -------------------------------------------------------
    //  getUserDateFormat: e.g. M/d/yyyy
    //  -------------------------------------------------------
    public static String getUserDateFormat() {
        String userLocale = UserInfo.getLocale();
        System.debug('@@ looged in user details :'+userLocale);
        getLocaleToDateTimeFmtMap();
        if (!localeToDateTimeFmtMap.containsKey(userLocale))    
            return 'yyyy-mm-dd';
        return localeToDateTimeFmtMap.get(userLocale).substringBefore(' ');
    }

    //  -------------------------------------------------------
    //  getLocaleToDateTimeFmtMap : Returns a map of user locale | date format for that locale
    //  -------------------------------------------------------
    public static Map<String,String> getLocaleToDateTimeFmtMap () {
        if (localeToDateTimeFmtMap == null)
            localeToDateTimeFmtMap  = new Map<String,String> {
            'ar'            => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ar_AE'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ar_BH'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ar_JO'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ar_KW'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ar_LB'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ar_SA'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'lb_LU'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'bg_BG'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'ca'            => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ca_ES'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ca_ES_EURO'    => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'cs'            => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'cs_CZ'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'da'            => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'da_DK'         => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'de'            => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'de_AT'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'de_AT_EURO'    => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'de_CH'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'de_DE'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'de_DE_EURO'    => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'de_LU'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'de_LU_EURO'    => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'el_GR'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'en_AU'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'en_B'          => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'en_BM'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'en_CA'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'en_GB'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'en_GH'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'en_ID'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'en_IE'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'en_IE_EURO'    => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'en_NZ'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'en_SG'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'en_US'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'en_ZA'         => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'es'            => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_AR'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_BO'         => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'es_CL'         => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'es_CO'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_CR'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_EC'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_ES'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_ES_EURO'    => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_GT'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_HN'         => 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            'es_MX'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_PE'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_PR'         => 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            'es_PY'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_SV'         => 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            'es_UY'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'es_VE'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'et_EE'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'fi'            => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'fi_FI'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'fi_FI_EURO'    => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'fr'            => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'fr_BE'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'fr_CA'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'fr_CH'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'fr_FR'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'fr_FR_EURO'    => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'fr_LU'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'fr_MC'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'hr_HR'         => 'yyyy.mm.dd',
            'hu'            => 'yyyy.mm.dd',
            'hy_AM'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'is_IS'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'it'            => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'it_CH'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'it_IT'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'iw'            => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'iw_IL'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'ja'            => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'ja_JP'         => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'kk_KZ'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'km_KH'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'ko'            => 'yyyy.mm.dd',
            'ko_KR'         => 'yyyy.mm.dd',
            'lt_LT'         => 'yyyy.mm.dd',
            'lv_LV'         => 'yyyy.dd.mm',
            'ms_MY'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'nl'            => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'nl_BE'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'nl_NL'         => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'nl_SR'         => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'no'            => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'no_NO'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'pl'            => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'pt'            => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'pt_AO'         => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'pt_BR'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'pt_PT'         => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'ro_RO'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'ru'            => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'sk_SK'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'sl_SI'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'sv'            => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'sv_SE'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'th'            => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'th_TH'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'tr'            => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'ur_PK'         => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'vi_VN'         => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            'zh'            => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'zh_CN'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'zh_HK'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'zh_TW'         => 'yyyy/mm/dd'
        };
        return localeToDateTimeFmtMap;
    }   



     /*
    Type Name: setStringToDateFormat
    Return type: Date 
    Parameter: Date as String
    Purpose : The purpose of creating the method is to set the string to date method. Here based on the logged in users locale we are changing forming the date from string passed from UI.
    */ 
    public static Date setStringToDateFormat(String myDate) {
        Date d;
        System.debug('@@@ date is :'+myDate);
        try{
            if(myDate != '' && myDate != null){
                String fetchDateLocl = Example2Ctrl.getUserDateFormat();
                String[] myDateOnly = myDate.split(' ');
                String[] strDate;

                Integer dayPosition;
                Integer monthPosition;
                Integer yearPosition;           
                Integer myIntDate;
                Integer myIntMonth;
                Integer myIntYear;


                //If the locale date is separated with a Dot(.)
                if(fetchDateLocl.contains('.')){
                    strDate = myDateOnly[0].split('\\.');
                    dayPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('d');
                    monthPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('m');
                    yearPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('y');


                    //Day calculation
                    if(dayPosition == 0){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 3){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 8){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 5){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }


                    //Month calculation
                    if(monthPosition == 0){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 3){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 5){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 8){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }

                    //Year calculation
                    if(yearPosition == 0){
                        myIntYear = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(yearPosition == 6){
                        myIntYear = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }                               

                }
                //If the locale date is separated with a hyphen(-)
                else if(fetchDateLocl.contains('-')){
                    strDate = myDateOnly[0].split('-');
                    dayPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('d');
                    monthPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('m');
                    yearPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('y');

                    //Day calculation
                    if(dayPosition == 0){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 3){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 5){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 8){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }


                    //Month calculation
                    if(monthPosition == 0){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 3){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 5){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 8){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }

                    //Year calculation
                    if(yearPosition == 0){
                        myIntYear = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(yearPosition == 6){
                        myIntYear = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }                
                }
                //If the locale date is separated with a front Slash(/)
                else if(fetchDateLocl.contains('/')){
                    strDate = myDateOnly[0].split('/');
                    dayPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('d');
                    monthPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('m');
                    yearPosition = fetchDateLocl.indexOf('y');


                    //Day calculation
                    if(dayPosition == 0){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 3){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 8){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }
                    else if(dayPosition == 5){
                        myIntDate = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }


                    //Month calculation
                    if(monthPosition == 0){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 3){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 5){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[1]);
                    }
                    else if(monthPosition == 8){
                        myIntMonth = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }

                    //Year calculation
                    if(yearPosition == 0){
                        myIntYear = integer.valueOf(strDate[0]);
                    }
                    else if(yearPosition == 6){
                        myIntYear = integer.valueOf(strDate[2]);
                    }                
                }
                d = Date.newInstance(myIntYear, myIntMonth, myIntDate); 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){                     
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.info,'Invalid Date'));
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred***: ' + e.getMessage()+e.getStackTraceString());  
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

This will work.

Comment: .Thank you now my functionality is working properly

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning date properly. The proper format for `Date.valueOf()` is:

```
string year = '2008';
string month = '10';
string day = '5';
string hour = '12';
string minute = '20';
string second = '20';
string stringDate = year + '-' + month
 + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + 
minute + ':' + second;

Date myDate = date.valueOf(stringDate);
```

I would suggest to simply use below code because of it's simplicity:

```
birthdateDateFormat = date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(SelectedYear), Integer.valueOf(SelectedMonth), Integer.valueOf(SelectedDay));
```

Refer [Date class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) documentation